# java.net.UnknownHostException @ Android (Simple HttpResponse-Code)

Tags: java, android, http

Dear Ladys and Gentleman,

I did my homework, I've googled a lot and I think I know where the Problem can be located:

I want to fetch some simple `JSON formated` data from local Apache. When I start a

httpclient.execute(httppost)

... I receive (via printStackTrace()):

```
02-04 13:26:12.292: W/System.err(9606): java.net.UnknownHostException: http://localhost/JSON/request2.php
02-04 13:26:12.292: W/System.err(9606): java.net.UnknownHostException: http://127.0.0.1/JSON/request2.php
(after including the line "127.0.0.1 www.localhost.alt" to my Host file):
02-04 13:26:12.292: W/System.err(9606): java.net.UnknownHostException: http://www.localhost.alt/JSON/request2.php
```

I really need help. Have you any Ideas?

Greeting,

John

---

**edit:**

I made some research and found this article:
[Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

As you can see localhost & 127.0.0.1 are reserved for the emulators loopbacks itself!

Thats why Dark is absolutely right when he said I have to use 10.0.2.2 there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well... the request works fine if I put it into a basic browser address field :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would have been nice if you posted your code along with the stacktrace.

But, Try using

```
  10.0.2.2 instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1
```

also add this

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks you both! Permission was already set. I don't know why, but 10.0.2.2 did work! Goddamn, if you would comment me this tricky fact I would even more thankful. :)